# lodash js function for check or value is higher or maybe less then zero

Tags: lodash

I use this condition quite often on my code base. Maybe exist lodash function for that:

note: totalDiscount can be `undefined`

```
const hasDiscount = totalDiscount > 0 || totalDiscount < 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Since lodash has [only three methods](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#clamp) on the Number type and Object ones are not suitable to have the code prettier, I would not look specifically for lodash.

Why don't you extract the condition in your own module, or you could even extend lodash object withour your own method like this:

```js
_.extend(_.constructor.prototype, {
  hasDiscount: function(discount) {
  return discount > 0 || discount < 0;
  }
});

if(_.hasDiscount(5)){console.log('yes')}
if(_.hasDiscount(-5)){console.log('yes')}
if(_.hasDiscount(undefined)){console.log('no')}
if(_.hasDiscount(0)){console.log('no')}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use plain javascript

`const hasDiscount = Boolean(totalDiscount)`

If `totalDiscount` is `undefined`, `null` or `0`, then hasDiscount will be `false`.
In all other cases, `totalDiscount` will equal to `true`.